# Split single column into multiple columns in SQL server based on number of records

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

I have around 28 records (which is dynamic, that is sometimes odd numbers of records and sometime even) in a single column.

Would like to split those into multiple columns based on a variable. There should be 5 or 6 records in each column.

Note: These 5 or 6 records is a variable and should be changed.

Example input table:

```
           Col1
           -----
            A
            B
            C
            D
            E
            F
            G
            H
            I
            J
            K
            L
            M
            N
            O
            P
            Q
            R
            S
            T
            U
            V
            W
            X
            Y
            Z
```

The required output table will be:

```
            Col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
            -------------------------------------
            A        F       K       P       U
            B        G       L       Q       V
            C        H       M       R       W
            D        I       N       S       X
            E        J       O       T       Y
                                             Z
```

Here is what I have tried and these two different query is providing different results:

```
            select Col1
                from Table1 where  Col1 is not null
                order by [col1] asc

--This provides all records

            WITH CTE AS
            (
            SELECT [Col1],
                   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) -1)%5 AS Col,
                   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) -1)/5 AS Row
            FROM Table1  where  Col1 is not null     
            )
            SELECT [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
            FROM CTE 
            PIVOT (MAX([COL1]) FOR Col IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])) AS Pvt
            ORDER BY Row
```

-- In this case records are missing (when number of records is high, as number of records can increase dynamically)

```
            WITH CTE AS
            (
            SELECT [Col1],
                   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) -1)%5 AS Col,
                   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) -1)/5 AS Row
            FROM Table1  where  Col1 is not null    
            )
            SELECT [0], [1]
            FROM CTE 
            PIVOT (MAX([COL1]) FOR Col IN ([0], [1])) AS Pvt
            ORDER BY Row
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: You say there should only be 5 or 6 rows, does that mean if you have 500 rows, you would need 100 columns? How much is your row count going to  fluctuate, and how will it effect your expected resultsd?

Comment: This is an example. However, I would like 5 columns with 100 records each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first allocate a column to each record, which can be done with `NTILE()`:

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT  TOP 26 Col1 = CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id))
    FROM    sys.all_objects
)
SELECT [Col1],
        5 - NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS Col
FROM Table1 ;
```

Giving:

```
Col1    Col
---------
Z       4
Y       4
X       4
W       4
V       4
U       4
T       3
....
Y       4
Z       4
```

Note, to start filling from the last column you have to allocate the columns in reverse order (`ORDER BY Col1 DESC`), then deduct this from total number of columns.

Then you can work out your row by ordering within your columns:

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT  TOP 26 Col1 = CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id))
    FROM    sys.all_objects
)
SELECT  Col1, Col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY Col1) AS Row
FROM    (   SELECT [Col1],
                    5 - NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS Col
            FROM Table1  
        ) c;
```

Giving:

```
Col1    Col     Row
--------------------
A       0       1
B       0       2
C       0       3
D       0       4
E       0       5
F       1       1
G       1       2
```

Then you can apply the pivot:

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT  TOP 26 Col1 = CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id))
    FROM    sys.all_objects
), CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Col1, COL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY Col1) AS Row
    FROM    (   SELECT [Col1],
                        5 - NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS Col
                FROM Table1  
            ) c
)
SELECT [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM CTE 
PIVOT (MAX([COL1]) FOR Col IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])) AS Pvt
ORDER BY Row;
```

Giving:

```
0       1       2       3       4
-------------------------------------
A       F       K       P       U
B       G       L       Q       V
C       H       M       R       W
D       I       N       S       X
E       J       O       T       Y
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Z
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

I have set up a sample table, and used a procedure with dynamic SQL for ease of re-use to demonstrate this solution, it seems to work as expected for me.

**SET UP**

```
-- SET UP TABLE AND INSERT RANDOM VALUES
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Table1;

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Col1 CHAR(2));
INSERT #Table1 (Col1)
SELECT  CONCAT(Letter, Number)
FROM    (SELECT  TOP 26 Letter = CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id))
        FROM  sys.all_objects) l
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n (Number);

GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#GenerateMatrix', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE #GenerateMatrix;

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #GenerateMatrix @Records INT, @Columns INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- GENERATE COLUMNS FOR PIVOT AND SELECT
    DECLARE @ColSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
            STUFF((SELECT   TOP (@Columns) 
                            CONCAT(',', QUOTENAME(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col1) - 1))
                    FROM #Table1
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


    -- FOR @Cols = 5 Generates "[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]"

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        CONCAT('SELECT ', @ColSQL, '
                FROM (SELECT  Col1, Col, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY Col1)
                    FROM    (   SELECT [Col1], Col = @Columns - NTILE(@Columns) OVER(ORDER BY Col1 DESC)
                                FROM (SELECT TOP (@Records) Col1 FROM #Table1 Col1) t
                            ) c) c 
                PIVOT (MAX([COL1]) FOR Col IN (', @ColSQL, ')) AS Pvt
                ORDER BY Row;');

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Columns INT, @Records INT', @Columns = @Columns, @Records = @Records;

END
GO
```

**TEST 1**

```
EXECUTE #GenerateMatrix @Records = 26, @Columns = 5;

0       1       2       3       4
----------------------------------
A1      A6      B2      B7      C3
A2      A7      B3      B8      C4
A3      A8      B4      B9      C5
A4      A9      B5      C1      C6
A5      B1      B6      C2      C7
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    C8
```

**TEST 2**

```
EXECUTE #GenerateMatrix @Records = 8, @Columns = 4;

0       1       2       3
----------------------------
A1      A3      A5      A7
A2      A4      A6      A8
```

**TEST 3**

```
EXECUTE #GenerateMatrix @Records = 40, @Columns = 8;

0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
-----------------------------------------------------------
A1      A6      B2      B7      C3      C8      D4      D9
A2      A7      B3      B8      C4      C9      D5      E1
A3      A8      B4      B9      C5      D1      D6      E2
A4      A9      B5      C1      C6      D2      D7      E3
A5      B1      B6      C2      C7      D3      D8      E4
```

**TEST 4**

```
EXECUTE #GenerateMatrix @Records = 50, @Columns = 6;

0       1       2       3       4       5
    ---------------------------------------
A1      A9      B8      C7      D6      E6
A2      B1      B9      C8      D7      E7
A3      B2      C1      C9      D8      E8
A4      B3      C2      D1      D9      E9
A5      B4      C3      D2      E1      F1
A6      B5      C4      D3      E2      F2
A7      B6      C5      D4      E3      F3
A8      B7      C6      D5      E4      F4
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    E5      F5
```

There are no records missing, and no rows with only null values in any of the tests.

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5f55aaefb2e78ac9f52dfd48284d0563)**

Comment: Thank you so much.The number of records are dynamic.( today its 28 , tomorrow may be 8,300,..), this script is either cutting off records or adding more NULL to it (in case of dynamic records). How can this script work perfectly on dynamic records? I am OK to fix the number of columns to minimum 5 or 10 (max). But , the number of rows(records) should be increase or decrease (based on dynamic number of records) and neither there should be any deletion/truncation of records nor complete column(/s) as null. OK to have one or two nulls along with the actual records in any of the column.

Comment: One more thing,  the English alphabets are not the actual data. It's just an example given. The real data is actually  of type "varchar"

Answer (score 1):

Empirically I was able to come up with the following pivot query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn-1) / 5 = 0 THEN Col1 END) AS col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn-1) / 5 = 1 THEN Col1 END) AS col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn-1) / 5 = 2 THEN Col1 END) AS col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn-1) / 5 = 3 THEN Col1 END) AS col4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (rn-1) / 5 = 4 THEN Col1 END) AS co15
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    (rn-1) % 5;
```

[image]

### Demo

The idea here is that each group (a row) is determined by at what point in modulus of 5 is the current row number.  The column, or pivot, is determined by how many multiples of 5 the current row number has.

Comment: This does not match the required output, in the question `Z` appears in the fifth column and the 6th row. `Z` does not appear in your output at all

Comment: @GarethD You're assuming that the `Z` belongs there or is expected there, which I am not sure is the actual case.  If the OP wants to hold more data, he should expand the size of the overall grid.

Comment: I am not sure it counts as an assumption to assume that is where `Z` should appear as this is where it appears in the question. You are assuming that the sample output in the question is not actually what the OP wants. I think this is probably a bigger leap that assuming that the example output is the output the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is getting five values in `Col`,

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) -1)%5 AS Col,
```

but only PIVOTing for 2 of them.

```
 PIVOT (MAX([COL1]) FOR Col IN ([0], [1])) AS Pvt
```

So you are ignoring all the `Col` with values of 2, 3, and 4.